# Entity Framework Core ChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, change-tracking

Please help me understand strange behaviour of Entity Framework Core v2.2.2
I have the class Country, which contains the collection of Regions, each Region refers to its owner - Country, and also Region may contains collection of SubRegions, each SubRegion refers to its SuperiorRegion.

See the UML-diagram below. 
[Domain model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xes5U.png)

And here is the code:

class Country

```
public class Country
{
    public Country(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Regions = new List<Region>();
    }

    // for EF
    protected Country()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Region> Regions { get; set; }

    public Region CreateRegion(string name)
    {
        var region = new Region(name, this);

        Regions.Add(region);

        return region;
    }
}
```

class Region

```
public class Region
{
    public Region(string name, Country country)
    {
        Name = name;
        Country = country;
        SubRegions = new List<Region>();
    }

    // for EF
    protected Region()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }

    public IList<Region> SubRegions { get; set; }

    public Region SuperiorRegion { get; set; }

    public Region CreateSubRegion(string name)
    {
        var region = new Region(name, Country);

        SubRegions.Add(region);
        region.SuperiorRegion = this;

        return region;
    }
}
```

Then I create a tree (so far it goes good):

```
var country = new Country("Best Country of the World");
var beachesRegion = country.CreateRegion("Region with beaches");
var hotelsRegion = beachesRegion.CreateSubRegion("Region with hotels");
var workRegion = country.CreateRegion("Region with hard work");
```

This is the structure I get:
[Object diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JUeI.png)

Checking:

```
Console.WriteLine(country.Regions.Count); // 2
```

And now more interesting. 
I create DbContext…

```
public class CountryContext : DbContext
{
    public CountryContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

… and connect Country to it:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CountryContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Countries")
            .Options;

using (var db = new CountryContext(options))
{
    db.Countries.Add(country);
}
```

And this time

```
Console.WriteLine(country.Regions.Count); //3!!!!!!!
```

This is what I get on the diagram:
[Object Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHiLw.png)

Actually, the question: how to make  the SubRegion not to be added to the Region collection of the Country?

Answer (score 1):

Your issues is that the two relationships of Regions and SubRegions with Country confuses EF.
When you ask EF to retrieve the Regions for you what it does is search all Regions that has their Country as the one you are navigating from which means SubRegions fulfill this criteria as well.

To solve this you either have to remove the `Country` property from `Region`. Or you create two classes `Region` and `SubRegion` where `Region` has `Country` property (maybe also no `SuperiorRegion` property if the hierarchy can not go deeper than two levels). And `SubRegion` does not have `Country` property.

Comment: I completely agree, but I also assume that there is a way to configure EF mapping, but I have not yet found how.

Comment: EF needs a way to tell top level Regions from sub Regions when loading them from DB and both of them live in same table. You are also associating Country with SubRegions so EF would think these also belong directly to the Country. You might try keeping Country null for Sub Regions but that design doesn't feel clean and can easily be broken by other code that forgets to respect this rule. Designing from the ground up so that your model can't easily be put into an invalid state is better.